RHEL9 - File 'pagecolor.sty' not found, tlmgr can see it, but kpsewhich cannot
I have a RHEL 9.4 system and I'm hitting the following error:
$ lualatex --halt-on-error --interaction=nonstopmode report.tex
...
! LaTeX Error: File `pagecolor.sty' not found.

Here's a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

I checked tlmgr and it seems to know about it:
$ tlmgr list --only-installed | grep pagecolor
i pagecolor: Interrogate page colour

But kpsewhich doesn't seem to know about it:
$ kpsewhich pagecolor.sty

I even tried installing all texlive packages just to see if there was something I didn't have installed, but this didn't resolve the problem either.
$ sudo dnf install texlive-*

If I try to see what provides pagecolor.sty, I get no results:
$ sudo dnf provides "*/pagecolor.sty"
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Error: No matches found. If searching for a file, try specifying the full path or using a wildcard prefix ("*/") at the beginning.

What am I missing?

If you were in a Debian bases system where is the apt-file tool one can use as apt-file search pagecolor.sty and it will show you which Debian package provided that file. Presumably there is something like that i RHEL, though I haven't used it for 10+ years.

Just for good measure, do you by any change have two LaTeX installations on your system? One upstream and one from RedHat (a lot of Linux users make this mistake, so better to get it out of the way).

welcome! why are you running lualatex as root? don't do that.

@daleif I just updated my post to include the output of dnf provides, but unfortunately there are no results. I do not have two LaTeX installations, only the one provided by dnf via dnf install texlive-*.
@cfr It was just a test system. I added a user and ran the same commands and updated my post but unfortunately the result is the same.

Then I'd recommend installing the upstream (tug.org/texlive) instead of using whatever split up redhat have made of the texlive version they took

@daleif I just installed the upstream and it works fine. Unfortunately, that method takes multiple hours to install. I'm trying to set this up as part of a deployment that will happen regularly and having to wait multiple hours isn't ideal. Do you know of a faster solution for RHEL systems?

Do you have very aggressive antivirus? Or very slow Internet? I think on Linux one is often capable of installing the full upstream texlive in less than 10min (perhaps plus the time to generate formats) by rsync the instalation folder to local disk.

That said. On Linux you should be able to just copy the entire installation from one computer to another

@daleif This would be deployed to a client so unfortunately that won't work. I managed to get around this by switching to MiKTeX :) Thanks for the help

What exactly is it you are doing here? And why does it matter if installation takes some time? Do remember that texlive also have installation schemes. I would be iffy about using miktex on Linux. But you do you.
